# Android - Add more levels to game without the need to download or update a new app from the Market

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I'm working on a platform=app for games and I want the user to be able to choose games like some kind of an add on, then it will download some file (a game) which my app knows how to read and work with.

Basically, what I want is to build a market without apk files.
Or to generate a new kind of apk files.

I hope you can understand my question..

Comment: Just so you know - although it's fine to create your own market, it is against the terms of the Android Market to sell an alternative market on it. So you'd have to distribute this manually.

Comment: what I want is only to update my app on its own without the need to go to the matket and go through the install process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way snesdroid works is it will play emulator files on the sd card, not sure if you could code the app to download files directly to the sdcard in a specific folder then have the app rescan that directory to refresh the levels.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is to simply send a level to the client using the network connection.

My maps look like: [[0,1,2],[0,-1-1]...] which can be nicely compressed.

Even a big level doesn't take more than a few seconds to download.
You just need to generate your own 'level' code reader.